# Two identical balls of mass m are attached via a pair of identical springs (spring constant k) and looped around a frictionless cylinder of radius R

Tags: homework-and-exercises

[image]The top ball is then displaced along the cylinder by a distance d, while the bottom ball is held fixed. At t = 0, both balls are released with zero initial speed. Ignore any effects due to gravity.
What are the resulting equations of motion, x(t), for each of the balls, where x is the position of the ball along the circumference of the cylinder? Assume that the cylinder is fixed, and ignore any strange effects (i.e. deviations from Hooke’s Law) arising from the curvature of the spring

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PhysicsSE! Please note that homework-like questions are considered off-topic. Please show your work or ask about a general concept or the specific part you're not understanding.

Comment: I had this problem on a mid-term in 1985. I remember it because most of the class got crushed by it.

Comment: Are you familiar with deriving equations of motions from a Hamiltonian/Lagrangian? If so did you manage to write down one?